# Starting ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET Forms Authentication, and I'm looking for a good article to help me start.

I've heard before that ASP.NET Forms Authentication uses a load of database tables preceeded with `aspnet_`, however any examples I've found don't show this.

For example I think theres an `aspnet_users` table?

How can I generate these tables, and is this what I'm supposed to be doing?

Any tutorials I find just tell me about adding the `authentication` tag into the web.config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aspnet_` tables are part of [SQL membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) implementation. Forms authentication works on top of `Membership Provider`.

Here are some articles

- [Use Forms Authentication with SQL Server in ASP.NET 2.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx)
- [Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx)

You can even roll out your own [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) which uses your existing table.

The [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) series is a good starting point. It covers all the security part of ASP>NET.

Comment: Cheers @Eranga! Just what I was after!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend the msdn articles :

- Forms Authentication Provider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx
- Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh.aspx

here is the schema used :
[image: here is the schema used]

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial from asp.net is worth reading:

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb

Following is the msdn page explaining the Aspnet_regsql.exe command to create the aspnet database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229862(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Cheers @Waleed. I've already checked this link but all they say about users/password storage is:

`Dim users() As String = {"Scott", "Jisun", "Sam"} Dim passwords() As String = {"password", "password", "password"}`

I was hoping for more database structure help

Comment: @Curt The aspnet_* databases for the membership, roles, and profile providers are created automatically for you when you start using the providers and the controls that use those providers. Otherwise, you can use the aspnet_regsql.exe to create the databases manually.